# Property 'original' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have an error cant figure it out.I'm still learning stuff.

below is the error appears:

```
  Property 'original' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "MediaSet" | undefined; original?: { __typename?: "Media" | undefined; url: any; width?: number | null | undefined; height?: number | null | undefined; mimeType?: any; } | undefined; small?: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | undefined; medium?: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } | { ...; }'.
  Property 'original' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "NftImage" | undefined; contractAddress: any; tokenId: string; uri: any; verified: boolean; }'.ts(2339).
```

what is the problem?

[import files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G82q.png)
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn3oz.png)

I keep getting this error and want a solution

Comment: It's kinda hard suggesting an answer because we don't know what `profileQuery` returns. It sounds like what `defaultProfile.picture` might be a [Union Type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/) between `MediaSet` and `NftImage`. The property `original` does exist in `MediaSet` but not on `NftImage`. Either check if this union makes sense in the backend, or check if `profileQuery.data.defaultProfile.picture.__typename === 'MediaSet'`